# How to make a java regular expression which matches a word in any language

Tags: java, regex

To match a word in english I would use pattern `[a-zA-Z]+`.

Is there any way how to write a regular expression which will match a word in any language? That is even if the word contains characters like `ščžé...`. I have no idea what possible characters exist in the world so I don't think that pure `[a-zA-Zščžé]+` would be enough...

Is there a better way to write this expression?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Pattern javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\p{L}+` should match a sequence of Unicode letters (i.e. characters that have the category L in Unicode). That's probably the widest possible definition though you may want to look at the [unicode categories list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) to decide whether you want to add other categories (e.g. there is one called "Number Letter").

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use some unicode character ranges

```
[a-zA-Z\u0000-\u1111]
```

or

```
[a-zA-Zš-é]
```

So you have to take a look at the unicode character code and add whatever range of special characters you have in the target language

Comment: That's not very precise, according to Palo's concern about "I have no idea what possible characters exist in the world". He'd still be missing some characters

Comment: @Lukas: good point that's only valid when you have a target language. plus Michael answer is way better ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know about `\p{L}+` either. Learned something! :)